# how to always use a 'set-method' to change the property of an object used as ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

in the controller I have:

```
$scope.foo = new Foo('test'); // foo.property now 'test'
```

in the view I have

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo.property" />
```

But I don't really want foo.property to be changed directly. 
I want it to be changed by calling a 'set method' for it, like

```
foo.setProperty('new-value');
```

So I know I could do something with watch like so:

```
$scope.$watch('myObject.property', function(newValue,oldValue) { 
    myObject.setProperty(newValue);
}
```

But I'll have this situation many times over again, so my question is if I can do this more automatically for every Foo?

or: **How can I best implement something in Angular so that every time someFoo.property is used as a ng-model it is changed by calling someFoo.setProperty(newValue)?**

Comment: may be im wrongly understand your question , but I think you can use Observer pattern for it ? can you or not ? 
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript

Comment: the Objects I use as models already have an event system. The problem is excactly that when their properties are modified, they don't automatically detect the changes, and do not trigger the usual events like their own 'setProperty' methods would.

Comment: are you sure what you changing the **properties** of object, and not changing the object at whole e.g `myObject = newObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the setter method on blur event:

```
<input type  type="text" ng-model="data.property" ng-blur="foo.setProperty(data.property)">
```

or use ng-change="foo.setProperty(data.property)"

Comment: I'm hoping to make a general solution with a directive or something of the kind for this at some point, but for now this will do. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want the foo.property model to not be changed due to User Interaction, yes? Why don't you `disable` the input box using HTML, which will make sure no user interaction ever changes the input value, and then use $watch? $watch is the perfect way to handle what you require. And as long as it is not a `deep watch`, there's no performance concern either.

Comment: I *do* want it to be changed through user input, but I want to use a method to change it (and do other things) rather than to have it being set 'directly'